# Wifi quality in percentage

Tags: network-programming, wifi, formula

I was wondering how I can determine the Wifi-quality based on 2 values:

```
Signal strength measured in dBm: e.g.: -51 dBm
Signal To Noise Ratio e.g. 70/70
```

I get these values from my system, but want to show a wifi-quality icon in my User Interface, so I should convert those values into a percentage using some kind of formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I figured it out for now. For those of you having the same issue, here's what I do.

```
guint32
nm_ap_utils_level_to_quality (gint val)
{
  if (val < 0) {
    /* Assume dBm already; rough conversion: best = -40, worst = -100 */
    val = abs (CLAMP (val, -100, -40) + 40); /* normalize to 0 */
    val = 100 - (int) ((100.0 * (double) val) / 60.0);
  } else if (val > 110 && val < 256) {
    /* assume old-style WEXT 8-bit unsigned signal level */
    val -= 256; /* subtract 256 to convert to dBm */
    val = abs (CLAMP (val, -100, -40) + 40); /* normalize to 0 */
    val = 100 - (int) ((100.0 * (double) val) / 60.0);
  } else {
    /* Assume signal is a "quality" percentage */
    val = CLAMP (val, 0, 100);
  }
  g_assert (val >= 0);
  return (guint32) val;
}
```